# Is C# .Net for desktop applications while C#/ASP .Net is for web applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm starting to learn C# and I'm confused as to what the difference is between C# and ASP.

From what I've learned, ASP .Net is most likely a server-side web development framework that can be used in C# code while .Net, on the other hand, is like a library of classes built in C#. However, where is the MVC from? How can I learn MVC using C#?

Comment: Too broad, if not - duplicate of [Difference between ASP.Net, C#.Net and VB.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051507/difference-between-asp-net-c-net-and-vb-net)

Comment: Sometimes you will hear people use the terms Classic ASP.NET or WebForms, which are synonymous.  I can't find a specific announcement, but the consensus is that WebForms is 'dead' in the latest ASP.NET5 and that means that ASP.NET MVC and WebApi are the tools you want to focus your learning on.

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree with the consensus on this one - I don't always agree that newer is better, but while C# is super pretty, classic asp.net ("WebForms") is... not pretty. At all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first concept to get is .NET which is a framework at the base of all the things you are asking about.  It has libraries and functions that can be used when programming.

The .NET framework can be developed with using a number of different languages.  C# is one of these languages, there are a number of others.

ASP.NET is a set of .NET libraries that have tools for developing rich web applications.  An ASP.NET application will be deployed in a web server, usually IIS, but it can use all of .NET behind it.  It can be programmed using any language available for .NET, including C#.

A .NET MVC applciation is an ASP.NET application, using the MVC design pattern and the special MVC tools provided in ASP.NET.

Comment: Also of note, ASP (which is not the same thing as ASP.NET) is an older technology that used VisualBasic for programming rich web sites.  It is obsolete, it was replaced by ASP.NET

Answer (score 3):

C# is a language. That language is a .net language (it uses the [.net framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework), compiles to CLR bytecode, etc.). Other .net languages also exist - most notably VB.net, but there are others as well.

ASP.net (that is, "classic" ASP.net, also often referred to as "WebForms") is a web development framework for use with the .net framework. You can write ASP.net code in C#; you can also write ASP.net code in VB.net or other .net languages. [ASP.net MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) is a different web development framework also for use with the .net framework - you can also write MVC code in C# or VB.net, and so on.

Comment: So you  mean to say, there's C# MVC.Net then?

Comment: @germikee I wouldn't say it quite like that, but yes - you can write mvc.net code using C#, in which case that project would be a C# MVC.net project.

Comment: Correct except there's no such thing as MVC.net. There is ASP.NET MVC which is a subcomponent of ASP.NET.

Comment: @TimRogers Fair enough. Everyone calls it mvc.net though :p, but being precise is good.

Comment: @neminem Maybe in your neck of the woods they do! I haven't heard it.

Comment: Yeah... I havent heard of MVC .Net, but I do get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

C# is a language.

ASP.NET is a framework that uses various compiled languages (C# or VB.NET) as well as markup languages (the default ASP.NET one, or Razor, or whatever else you plug into it). It's a bridge between your application and IIS.

And ASP.NET MVC is a set of libraries for ASP.NET, in particular giving a new markup language (Razor) and various IIS pipeline components (the URL rewriter, the various mechanisms to bind arguments to actions etc).

Answer (score 1):

MVC is just a design pattern that can be applied to any software design with a user interface.

- M -- Model -- This layer contains the data used by your application
- V-- View -- This is the actual user interface
- C -- Controller -- This layer governs the interaction between the model and

the view.

you can read more here:

[MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx)